# Laravel syncWithoutDetaching - Adding User (Authenticated by Passport Oauth2 Middleware) to Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have a route in my `api.php` file:

```
Route::post('/articleTotag', 'TagController@articleTotag')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Now in my `TagController.php` file, I'm trying to update my pivot table like so:

```
$tagType->articles()->syncWithoutDetaching($articleId, $user);
```

My pivot table fields are as follows:

```
+--------------------+
| Field              | 
+--------------------+-
| tag_id             |
| article_id         |
| user_id            | 
| created_at         | 
| updated_at         | 
+--------------------+
```

`tagId` and `articleId` are updated automatically courtesy of `syncWithoutDetaching($articleId, $user);`

I initialize `user_id` at

```
$user = $request->user()->id;
```

in my controller... and. `$articleId` is an array like this one

```
[
    "3a157d7e694941748779155f14280aee",
    "0ebf4ce42e04418a82d9bea5a765d855",
    "1aa5f38107f24fd49252dc1555959a0b",
]
```

However, `user_id` stays null in the pivot table after sync. How can I solve this? Basically, I want to keep track of which user added which tuple to the pivot table

Comment: `syncWithoutDetaching` only takes 1 argument ... it is just a shortcut for `sync($arg, false)`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships  "You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs: ..."

Comment: Thank you. Might have to do the attaching manually so I can feel that extra field with the username.